# Update components with URL

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to update other components but they are not being found. How must the path be set?

I always get the followig Message: `Cannot find component with identifier ":test" referenced from "tabViewCompAll:inboxTable"`.

I'm using `JSF 2.1` and `Primefaces 3.5`

Here is my code:

```
<ui:define name="contentLeft">
            <p:tabView id="tabViewPosts">
                <p:tab title="Inbox">
                    <p:dataTable id="inboxTable" var="task"
                        value="#{taskboxBean.taskboxList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        selection="#{taskboxBean.taskbox}"
                        selectionMode="single" rowKey="{task.TB_ID}">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":test"
                          />

                        <p:column headerText="Post">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{task.FROM_USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task.FROM_USER.LAST_NAME} (#{task.FROM_USER.EMAIL})" />
                            <br />
                            <h:outputText value="#{task.TASKTYPE.NAME}" />
                            <br />
                            <h:outputText value="#{task.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}" />                       </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="contentRight">
        <div id="test">
            <p:commandButton value="New Message"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{taskboxBean.taskbox.FIRST_NAME} #{taskboxBean.taskbox.LAST_NAME} "/>
            <h:outputText value="(#{taskboxBean.taskbox.EMAIL})"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{taskboxBean.taskbox.TASKTYPE.NAME}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{taskboxBean.taskbox.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}}"/>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys now get the following Message `"DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or you need to define rowKey attribute".`

But i have set a rowkey.
I changed the code following:

```
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="Taskbox" />
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contentLeft">
    <h:form id="postForm">

        <p:inputText id="searchText" value="#{taskboxBean.search}" />
        <p:watermark for="searchText" value="Search" />
        <p:commandButton id="searchButton" value="GO"
            actionListener="#{taskboxBean.searchPosts}" />
        <p:tabView id="tabViewPosts">


            <p:tab title="Inbox">
                <p:dataTable id="inboxTable" var="task"
                    value="#{taskboxBean.taskboxList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                    selection="#{taskboxBean.taskbox}"
                    selectionMode="single" rowKey="{task.TB_ID}" emptyMessage="">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":contentForm"
                      listener="#{taskboxBean.onTaskboxRowSelect}"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Post">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{task.FROM_USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task.FROM_USER.LAST_NAME} (#{task.FROM_USER.EMAIL})" />
                        <br />
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.TASKTYPE.NAME}" />
                        <br />
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contentRight">
    <h:form id="contentForm">
        <p:commandButton value="New Message"/>
        <h:outputText value="(#{taskboxBean.taskbox.EMAIL})"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: hi i found the problem i forget to set # rowKey="{task.TB_ID}" --> rowKey="#{task.TB_ID}"